# How to join a substring of a column (in one table) with the full value of another column (in another table)

Tags: sql, oracle

So I currently have a table with the following columns and entries:

```
ROW_ID        CODE           VAL
  1            US             50
  2            CAN            15
  3            MEX            12
```

And I have another column with the following columns and entries:

```
ROW_ID       CODE_METADATA         REGION
  1           US|451223123           8
  2          CAN|123123123           7
  3          MEX|41028               3
```

How would I be able to join the two tables on the CODE and CODE_METADATA columns?(respectively). I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
select t2.nvl(substr(code_metadata, 0, instr(code_metadata, '|')-1), code_metadata) as CODE
 from table1 t1
 join table2 t2 on t1.code = t2.CODE;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might join with the condition :

```
substr(t2.CODE_METADATA,1,instr(t2.CODE_METADATA,'|')-1) = t1.CODE
```

Comment: thanks! I had to take the table alias out and it worked. I wonder why??

Comment: @JohnWick since you prefix `nvl` with t2

Comment: Performing joins on functions will often give you sub-optimal performance, especially with large data volumes...

Comment: @BobC you're completely right for a production enviroment with huge data, I experienced such bottlenecks as a DBA.

Comment: @BobC what do you recommend then?

Comment: In this particular case, the answer is pretty simple; CODE_METATDATA should be two columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can also join using LIKE:

```
t2.CODE_METADATA LIKE t1.CODE || '|%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: substr(t2.CODE_METADATA,1,length(t1.CODE)) = t1.CODE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).